# Working with namespaces using Spin by Camunda

Tags: java, xml, xpath, namespaces, camunda

I´m working with Spin and I have a problem with the namespaces.

Let´s say I have the following XML:

```
<root xmlns="test">
    <sub></sub>
</root>
```

If I read this into a SpinXmlElement using

```
SpinXmlElement root = Spin.XML("<root xmlns=\"test\"><sub></sub></root>");
```

`<sub>` is automatically in the same namespace as `<root>` which is "test".

Now let´s add a new Element `<sub2>`:

```
SpinXmlElement sub2 = Spin.XML("<sub2></sub2>");
root.append(sub2);
```

After a xpath-test you can see that `<sub2>` is in no namespace.

```
try {
    root.xPath("./ns:sub2").ns("ns", "test").element();
} catch (final SpinXPathException ex) {
    System.out.println("This will throw an error, because <sub2> has no namespace.");
}
```

**Important:**
If you print `root` via `.toString()` you get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="test">
   <sub/>
   <sub2 xmlns=""/>
</root>
```

You can see, that `<sub2>` has an empty namespace here.

Now let´s add a new Element called "sub3". This time with the same namespace as `<root>`.

```
SpinXmlElement sub3 = Spin.XML("<sub3 xmlns=\"test\"></sub3>");
root.append(sub3);
```

If you do a xpath-test, you will see that `<sub3>` now is in the same namespace as `<root>` ("test").

```
try {
    root.xPath("./sub3").element();
} catch (final SpinXPathException ex) {
    System.out.println("This will throw an error, because <sub3> has a namespace.");
}
```

**Important:**
But if you print it again, you´ll get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="test">
   <sub/>
   <sub2 xmlns=""/>
   <sub3 xmlns=""/>
</root>
```

So, `<sub2>` and `<sub3>` have an empty namespace when you print them, but in reality `<sub3>` has a namespace and `<sub2>` has not.

**In the end my questions are:**
1. Is this behaviour a bug or am i making mistakes? Maybe it is the correct behaviour and I´m misunderstanding things.
2. Is it possible to ignore the namespaces while working with Spin?
3. Is there a way to add an element to an existing namespace without adding the `xmlns` attribute in the printed form?
e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="test">
<!-- All <sub> elements in the namespace "test" -->
   <sub/>
   <sub2/>
   <sub3/>
</root>
```

Thank you for your help in advance.